# XNA Gestures in a Class

Tags: class, input, xna, touch, windows-phone

Ok so I've been working on a project for Windows Phone 7.1 and I've hit a weird problem.

When I try to use Gestures I cannot set up the TouchPad.EnabledGestures anywhere but in Game1.cs

I have:

```
public class InputController : Controller
{
    public InputController()
    {

    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Hold | GestureType.Tap | GestureType.FreeDrag;
        base.Initialize();
    }

    public override void Update()
    {

        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

            if (gs.GestureType == GestureType.FreeDrag)
                _Acceleration += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And this does not work. 
If I delete "TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Hold | GestureType.Tap | GestureType.FreeDrag;"
And put it in Game1.LoadContent() instead it works...

Is there a way to get it to work inside the class?

Just to confirm the line DOES get called, and the EnabledGestures do appear in the TouchPad  data.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

As it turns out it was an initialisation issue.

Basically the data was being loaded from an uninitialised instance of TouchPad, THEN TouchPad was initialised. This caused a fair few errors

If anyone else has this problem make sure you get the order correct.
Make use of initialise functions rather than initialising when you declare the member variable :)